# what is the correct syntax of a post form in an http request

Tags: http, forms, post, restlet

What is the format of a form sent in an http post request ?
I am trying an http client program and want to send a form in an http post request.
I tried :

```
< FORM METHOD=POST >
< INPUT name="name" value="chriss">
< /FORM >
```

is this correct ? 
on the server side, when I try to get the value of name ( i use : form.getFirstValue("name")) I get  null.
(I am using restlet as my API.)
Can anyone help me please

Comment: Are you making an html page? Or a program that will sent form data via HTTP POST?

Comment: it is a java program that generates http requests, not an html page, does it make a difference ?

Comment: Are you working with "straight" TCP sockets? Or some sort of HTTP library?

Comment: i am using this : code.google.com/p/rest-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the `POST` request sent by an HTML form is usually using the "[`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4)" media type.

If your client is also a Restlet client, you should be able to use the `Form` class, set the required values for each name/value pairs, and get the representation to send using [`getWebRepresentation()`](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/data/Form.html#getWebRepresentation%28%29).

Essentially, the body will look like this:

```
name=chriss
```

If you had more parameters, they would be separated by `&`.

(If you were sending files, you'd use the `multipart/form-data` encoding instead.)

Answer (score 0):

An HTML reference will be helpful. There are plenty of good HTML books and online references.

```
<form method="post" action="/url/to/submit/to">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="chriss">
</form>
```

Comment: I used this, but still on the server side, when I try to get the value  of name, I get null and not chriss. does it make a difference if I am sending the http post form from an html page or from a java program ?